# RealmSwift currentUser cannot be called if more that one valid, logged-in user exists

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, realm

I have a **realm platform** and I can register and login a user fine. When I try to open a **Synced Realm** file with the current User it will not allow it and Xcode throws the error **currentUser cannot be called if more that one valid, logged-in user exists**. I have followed all the information I can find on realms docs and I can't make sense as to why this is happening. I have a Login View Controller and a separate View Controller that contains the realm file. Here is example code of the problem I am dealing with.

**LogInViewController**

```
import Cocoa
import RealmSwift

class LoginViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var username: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: NSSecureTextField!

    let realm = try! Realm()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: NSButton) {    
        let login = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: "\(username.stringValue)", password: "\(password.stringValue)", register: false)
        SyncUser.logIn(with: login, server: Constants.AUTH_URL, onCompletion: { [weak self] (user, err) in
            if let _ = user {
                if let mainWC = self?.view.window?.windowController as? MainWindowController {
                    mainWC.segueToHome()
                    print("Login Pressed")
                 }
             } else if let error = err {
                 fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
             }
         })
    }
}
```

**SecondViewController**

```
import Cocoa
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let config = SyncUser.current!.configuration(realmURL: Constants.REALM_URL, fullSynchronization: false, enableSSLValidation: true, urlPrefix: nil)
        self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
    }

    func save(data: Data) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(data)
            }
        } catch {
            print("there was an error saving data \(error)")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func saveData(_ sender: NSButton) {    
        let saveData = Data()
        saveData.textField = textField.stringValue
        save(data: data)
    }

    func loadData() {
        data = realm.objects(Data.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "timestamp", ascending: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this page help you solve the problem.

I solved the same problem.

```
    ///
    /// quit all other users session
    ///
    for u in SyncUser.all {
        u.value.logOut()
    }
    ///
    ///
    ///
    let creds: SyncCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(
        username: YOUR_USER,
        password: YOUR_PASS
    )
    SyncUser.logIn(
        with: creds,
        server: YOUR_AUTH_URL
    ) { (user: SyncUser?, err: Error?) in
        ///
        /// Your action ...
        ///
    }
```

After logOut and logIn, this method will success probably.

```
    let config = SyncUser.current!.configuration(realmURL: Constants.REALM_URL, fullSynchronization: false, enableSSLValidation: true, urlPrefix: nil)
    self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Realm with Firebase, a snippet like this will save you from authentication headaches.

Check to see if the SyncUser uid matches the uid from firebase, and sign out extraneous accounts.

```swift
        for syncUser in SyncUser.all {
            if(syncUser.key != (FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")) {
                syncUser.value.logOut()
            }
        }
```